# How do you modify the velocity multiplexer for turtlebot?

Tags: navigation, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Kobuki Turtlebot and would like to publish to the multiplexer on my own topic. The [official documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/cmd_vel_mux) hasn't done me well explaining how to modify the parameters.

Where can I find the config and YAML files discussed in the documentation and how can I edit them?
I am currently writing a rospy script for this, below is a simple implementation of what I'm trying to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('CmdVelMux_test', anonymous=True);
    velPub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel_mux/input/BSC', Twist, queue_size=10);
    Vx = Twist();
    Vx.linear.x = 0.1;
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        velPub.publish(Vx);
        rospy.spin;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243793/how-do-you-modify-the-velocity-multiplexer-for-turtlebot?/) by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2016-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoted from the page you gave "Since Hydro the package is renamed to yocs_cmd_vel_mux".

The yaml file is inside yocs_cmd_vel_mux package.
which is e.g. /opt/ros/indigo/share/yocs_cmd_vel_mux/param

To get there:

```
roscd
cd share
cd yocs_cmd_vel_mux
cd param
```

There you go:
example.yaml  reconfigure.yaml
The files that are described in the official doc that you mentioned

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piraka9011](https://answers.ros.org/users/27954/piraka9011/) on 2016-09-15**:
I have literally read the entire page three times and that small sentence never popped up to me. Makes me feel...unscholarly :P thanks for pointing that out!